# Creating Wizard HTML/CSS Interface Using jQueryUI

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a wizard-like interface where there are back/next and start-over buttons with the main content taking up the majority of the space. This is in HTML/CSS and using jQueryUI for an HTML Application (HTA) to only target IE8. Currently this is what I have:

**HTML:**

```
<body scroll="no">
    <div id="maincontent">
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <button class="bottombutton" id="backbutton">Back</button>
        <button class="bottombutton" id="startoverbutton">Start Over</button>
        <button class="bottombutton" id="nextbutton">Next</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bottombutton {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.centeredbuttons {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#backbutton {
    left: 10px;
}

#nextbutton {
    right: 10px;
}

#startoverbutton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}

#maincontent {
    position: fixed;
    height: 340px;
    width: 96.3%;
    top: 12px;
    left: 12px;
}
```

However, the result is extremely inconsistent when using jQueryUI's Accordion depending on the contents of the Accordion (the Accordion is always placed into #maincontent) and **I would like it to FILL the parent div** (#maincontent). The height can easily vary between pages despite the Accordion being set to heightStyle: "fill". (Content is loaded dynamically into #maincontent using load().)

This is how I would like it to look (and some pages do):

[image: Correct Look]

And how some pages look (some are much worse than this):

[image: Bad Look]

Comment: Where are your other tabs? I don't get why you are using an Accordion from these screenshots. Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CUPPT/1/)** mixing the demo from jQueryUI Accordion / Fill and your naming and buttons. Please update it with something reproducing your problem.

Comment: I don't always have other tabs. I'm using it as a consistent style for each page of the wizard. In the case of the screenshots posted there is only one tab.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/CUPPT/2/

Comment: Yes, if that could be replicated in IE8. However, it doesn't look anything like it does in Chrome, in IE8. This is how it looks: http://s30.postimg.org/hzvqjzgm9/new.png . I also can't even load JSFiddle in IE8.

Comment: JSFiddle in IE8 > yeah, you've to save it, then copy/paste the Share / Full screen result into IE8 (or append `/embedded/result/` to the URL) and it isn't even full height when it's what you want to observe so not so useful for this fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I discovered how to fix this. My issues were largely due to trying to load content into a div (#maincontent) that had my sizing parameters on it. What I needed to be doing is specifying my sizing parameters on the accordion div instead with only the height size specified on #maincontent. Here's what I changed to make it work :

```
#maincontent {
    height: 300px;
}

#modeaccordion {
    height: 300px;
    width: 96.3%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 12px;
    left: 12px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

Now when loading between pages you can't even tell that they're totally different html pages -- the size remains very steady.